# python-onvif-zeep | ptz.stop() throw an error | onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Action Not Support

Tags: python, ip-camera, zeep, python-onvif

im using [this](https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep/blob/zeep/examples/continuous_move.py) code for my task. and successfully run the moving method and the camera starts rotating. ones I call the stop() method it's throwing an exception. please help for solve this

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\onvif\client.py", line 23, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\onvif\client.py", line 153, in wrapped
    return call(params, callback)
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\onvif\client.py", line 140, in call
    ret = func(**params)
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 46, in __call__
    return self._proxy._binding.send(
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 135, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 229, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 391, in process_error
    raise Fault(
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Action Not Support

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/josh/Desktop/code/test.py", line 166, in <module>
    ptz.Stop({'ProfileToken': moverequest.ProfileToken})
  File "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages\onvif\client.py", line 26, in wrapped
    raise ONVIFError(err)
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Action Not Support
```

Answer (score 2):

Cameras may opt to use an alternate method for stopping movement. This I found by trial and error and later found the following post that explained it.

https://doc.milestonesys.com/latest/en-US/onvifdriver/why_the_onvif_driver_does.htm

The solution here is to remove this Stop request from the program. When you do need to stop movement, you will need a different strategy: send in x,y values of zero for continuous movement operation.

I also found that the relative and absolute movements are not really supported on my camera. They work, but they work identically to the continuous movement, not as expected

My camera company have been helpful. The bottom line is that you may need their assistance to know exactly what and how they support their device. For example, I cannot turn off auto-focus on mine.